# Register service within Entity Framework's internal IServiceProvider

Tags: entity-framework-core

It appears EntityFramework's `DbContext` class implements `IInfrastructure<IServiceProvider>` and handles its own dependency injection/resolution.
Is there a way to register your own Singletons/Transients within that container so that they would be available at runtime within a DbContext-derrived class?

Here's the code

```cs
            var services = new ServiceCollection();
            services.AddSingleton(typeof(IMyService), myServiceInstance);
            services.AddDbContext<BplnContext>();
            ServiceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

            var s1 = ServiceProvider.GetService<IMyService>(); // works

            DbContext = ServiceProvider.GetService<MyDbContext>();

            var infrastructure = DbContext as IInfrastructure<IServiceProvider>;
            var serviceProviderInternal = infrastructure.Instance;
            var s2 = serviceProviderInternal.GetService<IDateTimeProvider>(); // returns null
```

Are we not supposed to extend this internal service collection?

Thanks.